# how can i read a property of an object in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

```
objects [ {
    firstName: "Kristian",
    lastName: "Vos",
    number: "unknown",
    likes: ["JavaScript", "Gaming", "Foxes"],
    }....]
```

if this is my object, i need to read the word "`firstName`" and not the value of "`firstName`"

i know how to output the value of `firstName (   objects[0].fisrtName ) = "Kristian"`

but what i really need to read is if the object has a property called firstName, in case that the object doesnt have that property.

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you code isn't actually object since you use `[ ]`, it is more likely an array contain object.

This code should work, if you mistype the `[ ]`, just use `Object.keys(test)[0]` instead.

```js
let test = [{
  firstName: "Kristian",
  lastName: "Vos",
  number: "unknown",
  likes: ["JavaScript", "Gaming", "Foxes"]
}]
console.log(Object.keys(test[0])[0])
```

Comment: console.log(Object.keys(test[0])[0])   this solved my problem, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can check

```js
Object.keys(objects[0])
```

Or you can just check it like that

```js
if ('firstName' in objects[0]) {
  // ...
}
```

Comment: thank you this was useful

Answer (score 0):

You can achieved this using `Object.keys()`:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys